# Jmeter Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 28

Tags: java, jmeter, qa-developer

I am trying to Load test on the link:http://[dot4ap-mms-cr:8080/fms/Kernel/w_login.jsp]/

and getting this error message:

Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 28

Please could you help

Tuti

Answer (score 5):

Never put the whole URL into "Server Name or IP" input. It's better to configure [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) as follows:

- Server Name or IP: `dot4ap-mms-cr`
- Port Number: `8080`
- Protocol: `http`
- Path: `/fms/Kernel/w_login.jsp`

  [image: HTTP Request Configuration]

---

In the most recent JMeter versions (2.13  and 3.0) you can put the whole URL into `Path` input like:

[image: HTTP Request Path Configuration]

The recommended way of setting up application under test host, port and protocol is via [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element.